# Multiple DbContext classes use the same connection string?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

For example, I have following DbContext classes.

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext {
    ...
}
public class LogDbContext : DbContext {
    ...
}
public class FooDbContext : DbContext {
    ...
}
```

If a connection string named `AppDbContext` is on the `App.Config` and I want other DbContext classes to share the same connection string as `AppDbContext`, could I just pass the string "AppDbContext" as the parameter for the `ctor` of `LogDbContext` and `FooDbContext`. For example,

```
public class FooDbContext : DbContext {
    public FooDbContext : base("AppDbContext") { }
}
```

Does it have any side effects ?

## Update 2013/1/9

After trying @ShinH2S's suggestion and somethings, I give up this way, and decide give different Dbcontext derived classes with different connectionStrings and database. I have try [a test project and put it on GitHub](https://github.com/ToroLiu/ttTestMultipleDbContexts). It will throw a runtime exception when the entityframework detects the database scheme is changed because the `AppDbContext` and `FooDbContext` have different schemas. If I assign a `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` strategy to both DbContext derived classes, one of them will be dropped because the models is different to another.

## Update 2017/10

This is an old problem. In my memory, `EF6 and above versions` can have different migration history for multiple context in the same migration table.
I prefer [this answer at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32228384/419348). I had not been coding with C# about 2 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, there is no side effects. But if it was me I will just create a base class that inherits from DbContext class `BaseDbContext`then all the contexts (`AppDbContext`,  `LogDbContext` and `FooDbContext` ) will derive from `BaseDbContext`.

Comment: If those XXXDbContext derive from `BaseDbContext`, how do I make them have the same connection string so they use the same database ? Do I configure a connect string named `BaseDbContext` and all of derived classes use `BaseDbContext` for connecting ?

Comment: First you create one conection string named `BaseDbContext` in your configuration file.
in your `BaseDbContext` class you create a default constructor like that : `public BaseDbContext() : base("BaseDbcontext") { }`. That is all you have to do.

Comment: I need to try it. Those XXXDbContext are not in the same class library, and I failed to create tables as this way `public FooDbContext() : base("AppDbContext")`.

Comment: What is the error ?
I dont understand why you need to do `public FooDbContext() : base("AppDbContext")`. The constructor of your derived class must like that : `public FooDbContext() : base() {}`. There is no need to pass the name of the connection string beacause it is already in the base class.

Comment: The FooDbContext's tables are not created in the same database. And now I need to find out what happens. Today my work will focus on this problem.

Comment: How did you go @Toro? I having the same problem. I ended up combining the context into one class as there wasn't too much a need to. With @SlimH2S solution I tried though it also didn't work. Should only BaseDbContext have an Initializer class or all dbConexts have independent initizalizers?

Comment: I put a sample project at GitHub, you can find it on my `Update` post. I think that those different contexts will share the same `dbo._MigrationHistory` , and one of them will treat the db scheme has been changed due to the this table. I give up sharing the same connectionstring, and assign new one string to each context.

Comment: I think you must watch Julie Lerman video (http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=efarchitecture&highlight=julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m2-boundedcontext*6#efarchitecture-m2-boundedcontext) about Bounded Contexts and how to make multiple context to point to the same database. It will help you a lot ;)