# Creating Multiple DbContext in Entity Framework example

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am going to develop a project where i would like to use Entity Framework 5 with Code First Approach. I want to use multiple DbContext file. So can anyone please give an example with with a sample project to demonstrate multiple DbContext file. I will be highly grateful.

Thanks .

Comment: Don't! Having more than one DbContext class surely indicates that you do something terribly wrong.

Comment: @ThomasWeller That's not true. There can be very good reasons to have contexts that cover separate aggregates of an application. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

Comment: If i have lots of entity classes more than 50 then i think to have multiple dbcontext file for performance omptimization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a good idea, because there are many side effects. Have a look here:

[Entity Framework: One Database, Multiple DbContexts. Is this a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea)

But in fact it should be working when you look at the [latest comment on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea/20490554#20490554). Just define the `ConnectionString` in the context and set it to the same in every context class.

If you need more informations please provide us with more informations what you are trying to achieve and what's your requirements.