# How to implement a dbContext in multiple classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I am not sure the best way to handle the `DbContext` when one method "*needs*" 2 `DbContext` objects. I have classes that do the normal CRUD operations, and after each insert/edit, I log the changes that were made -using `Log_History` entity. Rather than duplicating the same code in multiple classes, I created a public static method for adding a new `Log_History` entity.

My initial thought was this can't be a good idea. Would there be a concurrency issue using 2 `DbContext` objects? I am not sure if I understood correctly, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea) question got the response that multiple contexts are okay. What about passing my `DbContext` in `CreateOrder()` as an argument of `AddHistoryNote()`; would that be an acceptable approach?

```
public class Log
{

public static void AddHistoryNote(Guid UserId, string Type, string Detail)
{
    using (rsContext repo = new rsContext()) {
        Log_History trans = new Log_History {
            UserId = UserId,
            Description = Type,
            Detail = Detail,
            HistoryDate = DateTime.Now
        };

        repo.Log_History.Add(trans);
        repo.SaveChanges();
    }

}

}

public class DoStuff
{

private void CreateOrder(BT.TransactionInfo TransDetails)
{
    using (rsContext repo = new rsContext()) {
        rsDataAccess.Order newOrder = new rsDataAccess.Order {
            Amount = TransDetails.Amount,
            OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
            Status = Status.RIDER_PAID,
            RequestId = TransDetails.RequestId
        };

        ' Add hisotry here 
        Log.AddHistoryNote(TransDetails.UserId, "TransactionType", "My history note");

        repo.Orders.Add(newOrder);
        repo.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just pass the DBContext in as a parameter and use it from there?

Comment: That is what I meant by "passing the DbContext in CreateOrder() as an argument of AddHistoryNote()." I know it would work, but I needed some assurance that it would be an effective approach.

Comment: Sorry :)  Yes, in that case I can't see there being an issue.  It also allows you to manage the transaction anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think is a problem here, but nothing is.

There are no concurrency issues with calling a static method like this.  Your DbContext itself is not static (if it was, that would be a problem) and you are newing up a new instance.

That's not to say I would recommend doing this, but it's not going to be an error.

Comment: What would you recommend, or why would you not recommend this?

Comment: @KRob - I wouldn't recommend it because it's unnecessary.  I would probably implement it as a C# extension method on the DbContext, or a method of the DbContext.