# Entity framework: two distinct contexts and one database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is it possible, in a code-first approach, to define two different context classes and use them simultaneously?

The database schema is already given and I cannot modify it (besides the creation of some new tables).

The problem I'm facing is that I'm getting "The model backing... has changed" error. It seems there's some  kind of collision between the two contexts.

Note that each context includes a different set of tables, so sync problems aren't a concern.

Comment: WHEN exactly you are getting the error?

Comment: As soon as I instantiate two contexts, or just one context that isn't the same instantiated in a previous execution.

Comment: From the package manager console , what do you get if you run a test migration? Does it show anything in the up or down methods? `Add-Migration TestMigration`

Comment: You should set Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null); in Global.asax to prevent EF6 trying to sync the db schema with your model.

Comment: Also check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using EF 6 or higher, this can be done either by the [ContextKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.contextkey(v=vs.113).aspx)-Property of [DbMigrationsConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration(v=vs.113).aspx) (this will make the MigrationsHistory table multi tenant by ContextKey) or by setting [HasDefaultSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.hasdefaultschema(v=vs.113).aspx) in [OnModelCreating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx) (this will enable multiple MigrationsHistory tables, one for each schema). For further instructions see the [Documentation](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations).