# Create a database relationship between 2 entities in different Entity Framework DbContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two Objects (UserProfile and Login) that resides in different assemblies and I have to create a relationship between them in SQL Server (I don't care about the DbContext relationship, but I'd like to assure the database referential integrity between the their respective tables).

The easiest way is to update the database (I am using code first) and run a alter table to create the relationship however I think this approach is kind of dirty (even if using SqlResource in Up method).

I tried unsuccessfully to create this relationship using HasOptional and Map methods (fluent api says that ProfileId isn't a reference type when I try something like "HasOptional(a => a.IdUsuario)...").

```
// UserContext's Classes (Assembly 'A')
public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    // some properties omitted
}

public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<UserProfile> UsersProfiles { get; set; }
}

// SecurityContext's Classes (Assembly 'B')
public class Login
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; } // UserProfile's FK
}

public class SecurityContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to reference both classes, include navigation properties and use "modelBuilder.Ignore<>" to select which class I want to really synchronize in each context, but this ends in a circular reference problem.

I receive the message "The navigation property 'UserProfile' is not a declared property on type 'Login'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property." if try to create fake classes just to mapping purposes.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are missing some points.

The `UserProfile` is a **weak entity**, it is a dependant of `Login`. The relationship is 1:1. 1 `Login` has 1 `UserProfile`.

Your classes should be like this:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    //UserProfile does not have its own Id,
    //Its Id is the LoginId, which is the primary key and a foreign key
    //It ensures the 1:1 relationship
    public int LoginId { get; set; } // PK and FK
    // some properties omitted
    public Login Login { get; set; }
}

public class Login
{
    public int LoginId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    //Login does not have UserProfile fk
    //because it is the Principal of the relationship
    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
    .HasKey(i => i.LoginId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Login>()
    .HasKey(i => i.LoginId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Login>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.Profile)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(i => i.Login)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Generated Migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Logins",
    c => new
        {
            LoginId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            UserName = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.LoginId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.UserProfiles",
    c => new
        {
            LoginId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.LoginId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Logins", t => t.LoginId)
    .Index(t => t.LoginId);
```

**EDIT**

Since `Login` does not belong to the domain assembly, `Login` is the **weak entity**. `Login` has a dependency of `UserProfile`.

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; } // PK
    // some properties omitted
    // we don't have Login property here
}

public class Login
{
    //login pk must be userprofile FK
    //so it ensures the 1:1 relationship
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; } //PK

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }// UserProfile's FK
}
```

Mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Login>()
    .HasKey(i => i.UserProfileId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Login>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.Profile)
    .WithRequiredDependent();
```

Generated Migration

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.UserProfiles",
    c => new
        {
            UserProfileId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserProfileId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Logins",
    c => new
        {
            UserProfileId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            UserName = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserProfileId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.UserProfiles", t => t.UserProfileId)
    .Index(t => t.UserProfileId);
```

Comment: Fabio, you're right in some points but your solution has a problem because, as I explained, I can't reference the Login in the UserProfile class (and vice versa) because they're in different assemblies and I'll get in the circular reference problem so I can't create the Login navigation property (the UserProfile class resides in the domain layer while the Login resides on crosscutting/security layer).
.

Thanks. (Obrigado.)

Comment: So, in your case you just have to do opposite. Login is the weak entity. Take a look at my edited answer

Comment: Doing this way now my DbContexts have the correct relationships, but the context that contains the login attempts to recreate the UserProfile table when I try to run the Update-Database (it already exists in the database). I tried to create a migration (Add-Migration) using the key -IgnoreChanges, but this also makes the constraint to be ignored (that is just the opposite of what I need). I think that mix two contexts with existing entities/tables isn't a good approach...

Comment: Try to use `modelBuilder.Ignore<UserProfile>();` Mixing two context to a single database is a good approach when you have a lot of entities, and also for DDD structures. Take a look at these link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea

Comment: This problem is not related to the question, If you do not find an answer, you should ask it in another question

Comment: The ".Ignore<>" causes error in the foreign key mapping.

Comment: Fabio, in relation to my original question "How to create a database relationship between two entities in different Entity Framework DbContexts," your answer and comments are correct. Throughout our exchange of comments I saw that what I need is something simpler and therefore does not justify the extra complexity to generate additional context or any other control mechanisms for the two contexts coexist harmoniously.

Your edited answer would solve my problem if I did not have other design constraints that do not fit in this discussion. Thank you for your help.