# Join on tables from different DbContext - model first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In an app with EF6.0, I have two DbContext's created by model first, `Schema1.DbContext1` and `Schema2.DbContext2`.

Now I need to do a join on two entities, `EntityA` from `Schema1.DbContext1` and `EntityB` from `Schema2.DbContext2`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just doing it?

Something like:

```cs
var result = context1.EntityA.Join(context2.EntityB, a=>a.Key, b=>b.Key, (a,b)=>new {a,b});
```

I'm not sure how nice the SQL will be, since the join is done in LINQ. You'd want to test and see how it is actually being implemented!

Comment: You can't query from two different contexts, it throws an error. It makes sense because those are two different connections to DB

Comment: Also, I don't want to do the join in memory, by getting results from each query first and then do the join, I'd like to have it run as a SQL join in the DB.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to approach the problem differently then. Maybe create a view and reference it? The model-first approach has its limitations!

Comment: If by "schema" you mean a SQL schema, I don't see why you can't reference both. If you mean DBContext, then it likely would be a problem. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use stored procedures, this is a case for it.  The proc can join the two entities at the database level across databases.  Whichever db is appropriate, you can then map that proc in your entities model and use it.  I say 'if you can' because I've seen shops that prohibit all SP's in favor of only EF.

Comment: Yes, they're the least sexy thing ever until you run into this type of a case and try any other solution.  BTW, if you're "that" Don Box, your Essential Com has occupied a spot in my bookcase (well-worn) for around 20 years.

Comment: hahaha. You made my day. I'm not him, but for some strange reason his name stroke a chord in my head for more than a decade. Unfortunately I never finished reading his book.

Comment: by the way, my question, was a bit nonsense in a way. As far as I remember, I just needed to create a new DBContext with tables I need to run query on.

Comment: Right, there's a design pattern, DDD - Bounded Context,  for that approach.  I was assuming you could not do that.  Here's an article on how to implement it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx