# Add new related tables in CodeFirst

Tags: code-first

This is my attempt to create new tables using code-first. My objective is to have a `Name` table with a relation to the `PhoneNumber` table.  It actually does nothing to the database, so I must be missing something important.

My project is the default ASP MVC app.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ZeroCloud1.Models
{
```

//included in ApplicationDbContext
   // public virtual DbSet Blogs { get; set; }
    //    public virtual DbSet Posts { get; set; }

```
     public partial class Blog
{
    public Blog()
    {
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public partial class Post
{
    public string PostString { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }
}
}
```

> PM> Add-Migration 'TestClass3' Scaffolding migration 'TestClass3'. The
>   Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your
>   current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the
>   changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you
>   make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this
>   migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration
>   TestClass3' again.
>
> PM> Update-Database Specify the '-Verbose' flag to
>   view the SQL statements being applied to the target database. Applying
>   explicit migrations: [201704091548342_TestClass3]. Applying explicit
>   migration: 201704091548342_TestClass3. Running Seed method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize you `[can only have one DbContext when using Code-First]`[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11198345/73804)

So I used my ApplicationDbContext that was came with the default ASP MVC site and it worked