# Entity Framework: Having two contexts in the same database with one context dependent to the other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having a difficulty when doing the automatic migration. Here is the case:

I have 2 contexts, one is EAccounting context and one is ECommerce context. EAccounting context has:

```
public DbSet<EA_Item> Items { get; set; }
```

And there is entity inside the ECommerce context which dependent to `EA_Item`

This is the entity in ECommerce that has `EA_Item` dependency in it:

```
public DbSet<EC_Product> Products { get; set; }
```

And this is the `EC_Product`:

```
[Table("EC_Product", Schema = "dbo")]
[Serializable]
public class EC_Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Product Id")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Item Id")]
    [Required]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Published")]
    public bool Published { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is Featured")]
    public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public virtual EAccounting.Models.EA_Item Item { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual ECommerce.Models.EC_Category Category { get; set; }

    public EC_Product()
    {
        ItemId = 0;
        CategoryId = null;
        IsFeatured = false;
    }
}
```

It has `EA_Item` whenever I run the program it gives me:

> entity framework migration There is already an object named "EA_Item" in the
>   database.

EAccounting and ECommerce assemblies are not in one, they are seperated. EAccounting does not know there is ECommerce assembly, but ECommerce assembly requires EAccounting assembly to be loaded.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What are you going to solve with the two contexts? Raising pain?

Comment: I am implementing plugin system with MEF that is why plugin EAccounting can stand alone but plugin ECommerce requires EAccounting to be installed first

Comment: I think this is what you are trying to accomplish:      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea