# IdentityServer4 PersistedGrantDbContext & ConfigurationDbContext

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations, identityserver4

New to IdentityServer 4. I followed the IdentityServer4 EntityFramework sample [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) on the documentation.

After the migration script is run

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerPersistedGrantDbMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrantDb
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerConfigurationDbMigration -c ConfigurationDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/ConfigurationDb
```

It works and now my application has 3 DB Contexts.

- ApplicationDbContext
- PersistedGrantDbContext
- ConfigurationDbContext

My question is what are the two DB contexts for? What is the difference between the application db context and the other two?

If I update or add any models, do I need to update all three? Or when should I run a migration on the ApplicationDbContext and when to run on the other two.

Any insight or literature on these is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: The idea is to split the entities so you only consume the tables you need and so the app doesn't need to load everything at once for performance and also to restrict access. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea

Comment: @Jasen Makes sense, thanks. Any insight on how the PersistedGrantDbContext and PersistedGrantDbContext are used in IdentityServer4?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of IdentityServer. I think they're keeping the grants in a separate store from the server configuration from your application store.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Figured it out. Leaving this for anyone confused about this as I was.

There are 3 DB contexts and, as @Jasen mentioned, it is to split up access to the entities, or tables.

IdeneityServer4 + EntityFramework + ASP.NET Identity creates the following tables in the database:

[image: SQL Server Tables]

The contexts are used to reference the following:

ApplicationDbContext - responsible for users involved with ASP.NET Identity so tables

- dbo.AspNetRoleClaims
- dbo.AspNetRoles
- dbo.AspNetUserClaims
- dbo.AspNetUserLogins
- dbo.AspNetUserRoles
- dbo.AspNetUsers
- dbo.AspNetUserTokens

PersistedGrantDbContext - responsible for storing consent, authorization codes, refresh tokens, and reference tokens

- dbo.PersistedGrants

ConfigurationDbContext - responsible for everything else remaining in the database

So in regards to migrations, if I update any of the AspNet Identity models (i.e. ApplicationUser) then I would run the migration on the ApplicationDbContext. Any client tables or other scopes would be run on the ConfigurationDbContext. And to access the entites (or tables) would be the corresponding context.