# One DbContext and multiple database, EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first

This is my first question, and I know I should search before asking anything, I am sure that I have done search but I didn't find appropriate information.

I am using code-first approach to implement my Context and my Models,
So I have a simple Context like:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public partial class MultipleContext : DbContext
{
    public MariaDBContext(string connection) : base(connection)
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer<MultipleDBContext>(new MariaDbInitializer());
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().ToTable("test")
            .HasKey(e => e.ID);
    }
}
```

and my model:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Family { get; set; }
}
```

and I have two `connectionstrings` like below:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="MariaDBContext" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=xx;database=sb1" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="SqlDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=db1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and my EF config :

```
<entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
```

I want to write to different Db just by changing `ConnectionString` like:

```
MultipleDBContext context = new MultipleDBContext(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MariaDBContext"].ToString());
var xx = context.Tests.Where(x => x.ID > 0).ToList();
context.Tests.Add(new Test()
{
    Name = "name",
    Family = ""
});
context.SaveChanges();
xx = context.Tests.Where(x => x.ID > 0).ToList();
//Use sql connection

MultipleDBContext sqlContext = new MultipleDBContext (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDBContext"].ToString());
var sqlTest = sqlContext.Tests.Where(x => x.ID > 0).ToList();
sqlContext.Tests.Add(new Test()
{
    Name = "name_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(),
    Family = "family_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(),
});
sqlContext.SaveChanges();
sqlTest = sqlContext.Tests.Where(x => x.ID > 0).ToList();
```

the first `context` works fine but the `sqlcontext` get the below exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll 
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

but if I remove the `DbConfigurationType` decoration then the second `sqlContext` works fine the first one give below exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>   Additional information: Login failed for user 'root'.

I know that is because of `DbConfigurationType` which can define in application start or decorate on `Context` or defined in config file....

but how can I have this (multiple `connectionstrings` and one context)?

Comment: It is because of different provider.

Comment: Pretty sure EF works on the premise of [1context = 1database] at a time.

Comment: @Wurd, So you say there is no way to implement above scenario ?

Comment: Is one context for MySql db and the other context for SQL Server? Also why is the type of one context `SqlDBContext` and the other one `MariaDBContext` but you only provided implementation for `MariaDBContext `? There is no issue for the different instance but same type context to operate on multiple databases, provided that the schema will match your entities.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius, I have missed it, I just edited, I used `MultipleDbContext` for different `ConnectionString`

Comment: Looking at your connection strings - one of the connection strings is for `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` provider whereas your EF config only configured for `<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"`

Comment: I just remember having an argument with someone that switching connection strings could be done but I was proved wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is because of configuration in config file (multiple provider),

As far as I know you should change provider at run time for related database..

So as your configuration file seems configed for `MySql` provider :

```
 <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
 </providers>
```

so you must define provider per `connectionstring` like below(just for sample):

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
</providers>
```

but by the above config the problem won't gone because there are some anothers tips and tricks to do this such as different `schema`  in different database,different attributes like `[DbColumn(msSqlName: "Id", oracleName: "ID", postgreSqlName: "id")]` and etc....

So as I experience this is better to have separate context per database but at the end there are some helpful links which will help you to resolve the problem.

the first is [Entity Framework Multi DB Support](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1062375/Entity-Framework-Multi-DB-Support) and [This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1237253/Entity-Framework-Core-with-multiple-DB-Contexts-Sc)

apart from anything you should know is this good idea to have multiple db per single context or not, [this issue discussed before here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea).

Hope this answer help you.