# One entity belonging to different DataContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an entity that could belong to two different DataContext and it's a element that inherits Identity.
I have on DataContext for Identity and one DataContext for the rest.

Is it a bad idea to include the element in both DataContext?

Comment: Why not just shrink everything to one DataContext inheriting from `IdentityDbContext` which down it's hierarchy inherits from `DbContext`?

Comment: _Bad idea_ is subjective. You will add complexity to your application with multiple DbContext -- I wouldn't do that unless I had a specific reason. This  points out some of the problems you may encounter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea.

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

In short Yes. 
But if you really want to keep it like that than instead using an entity directly from db context you could make two entities for each context than map them into an object that you would use for your purposes.