# A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed Asp.net EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a small issue i keep getting I am using view components on a page and I keep getting the following. I am using asp.net core 3.1 and ef core 3.1

> A database operation failed while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context
> before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by
> different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more
> information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913. There are pending
> model changes for MISDBContext In Visual Studio, use the Package
> Manager Console to scaffold a new migration for these changes and
> apply them to the database:
>
> PM> Add-Migration [migration name] PM> Update-Database Alternatively,
> you can scaffold a new migration and apply it from a command prompt at
> your project directory:
>
> > dotnet ef migrations add [migration name]
> > dotnet ef database update

I have checked on SO and it recommended that you add the following to your class now I am i right in thinking i dont need the second context at all is that what is causing the issue in my case. I added the line

```
ServiceLifetime.Transient
```

Apparently the above line allows for more concurrent connections to the context.

```
services.AddDbContext<MISDBContext>
 (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
 options.UseSqlServer(
 Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

This is the typical layout of my view component I think in fact it may be this one that is causing the issue cause im trying to access the user store at the same time as the context.

```
 private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync() => _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    public async Task<Guid> GetCurrentTennantId() {
        ApplicationUser usr = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        TempData["TeannantId"] = usr?.Id;
        Guid.TryParse(usr?.Id, out Guid resultTennantId);
        return resultTennantId;
    }
    private Task<List<ApplicationUser>> GetItemsAsync() {
        string currentUser =  GetCurrentTennantId().Result.ToString();
        var excludeCurrentUser= _userManager.Users.Where(w => w.Id != currentUser).ToListAsync();
        return excludeCurrentUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which DbContext is `_userManager` using? Are you using two dbContexts at the same time? Also, do you *really* need two dbContexts for the same database? Some interesting read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197754/entity-framework-one-database-multiple-dbcontexts-is-this-a-bad-idea).

Comment: Its using MISDBContext that is the problem i removed the offending one.

Comment: In my opinion, to solve this issue, you should make sure you have always await async calls immediately when you call GetCurrentUserAsync and GetCurrentTennantId method.

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently the above line allows for more concurrent connections to the context.

No; it creates a new context for each request. Each context can only be used for one operation at a time. So, e.g., if your context was previously a singleton, then only one HTTP request could make an operation at a time.

> I think in fact it may be this one that is causing the issue cause im trying to access the user store at the same time as the context.

This code *by itself* can't cause the problem, but if this pattern is repeated in your code base, then it could cause the problem.

In summary, [use `async` and `await` for all `Task<T>`-returning methods, unless the method is trivial](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). E.g., `GetCurrentUserAsync` is trivial (it's just passing through to another method), so it's fine to elide `async` and `await` there. `GetItemsAsync` is definitely not trivial, so it should be using `async` and `await`:

```
private async Task<List<ApplicationUser>> GetItemsAsync() {
  string currentUser = (await GetCurrentTennantId()).ToString();
  return await _userManager.Users.Where(w => w.Id != currentUser).ToListAsync();
}
```

If you apply `async` and `await` in a similar manner across your codebase, you should resolve the concurrent context issue.