# How to configure several contexts in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I would like to ask how can I configure correctly connection to the database server. My actual problem is when `GamesContext`, `UserAccessContext` and `PaymentsContext` are in the state like you see below (not commented) I can not do

```
PM add-migration -Context -[ModuleContextName]Context [ModuleMigrationName]
```

When I comment two of three it works correctly. For example thrown exception

> An exception was thrown while activating Jookli.Payments.Infrastructure.PaymentsContext

Each module uses the same database and the same connection string as you can see here:

```
public void  ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddSwaggerDocumentation();

        ConfigureIdentityServer(services);

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IExecutionContextAccessor, ExecutionContextAccessor>();

        services.AddDbContext<UserAccessContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(_configuration[JookliConnectionString]);
        });

        services.AddDbContext<GamesContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(_configuration[JookliConnectionString]);
        });

        services.AddDbContext<PaymentsContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(_configuration[JookliConnectionString]);
        });
}
```

One of my context. Other are similar (having 3/5 same entites)

```
public class PaymentsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<OutboxMessage> OutboxMessages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InternalCommand> InternalCommands { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InboxMessage> InboxMessage { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CardEntity> Cards { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserEntity> Users { get; set; }

        private readonly ILoggerFactory _logger;
        public PaymentsContext(DbContextOptions options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) : base(options)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory;
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

and table config

```
internal sealed class UserTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserEntity>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Payments_User");

            builder.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
        }
    }
```

How to configure different contexts so I can use PM migration command?

Comment: Are these all inherited from same base db context? if so please look at this question....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75349449/ef-core-multiple-dbcontext-with-one-database..

I think you may need to correctly configure your context's on Model Creating method...

Comment: I read this article thanks but there is no asnwer on my question. Something similar but not exactly same problem. In my Contexts each Table has prefix like Payments_User, Games_User and so on, so it is not associated with table names.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 `DbContext`s with distinct schemas that you want to import into a single database this looks to be possible, you just need to configure each to use a separate __EFMigrationsHistory table:

For instance in a PaymentsContext:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
     options.UseSqlServer(
        _connectionString,
        x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__PaymentsMigrationsHistory", "dbo"));
}
```

... then similar for each of the other DbContext instead of all trying to use the single __EFMigrationsHistory table.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was struggling in mind with this since last day, and I could not sleep of this. I did as you wrote and it works, thank you !